# Java Discord JDA move users

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm coding a discord bot which creates a personal voice channel if you join a main channel. My problem is that I can't move the user in his private channel because I can't create the GuildController which you need to move users. Have you any idea how I can move the user without the GuildController or how I can create the GuildController? I just tried to import the GuildController from the Discord API but Eclipse didn't found it. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Guild#moveVoiceMember](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#moveVoiceMember(net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member,net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.VoiceChannel)) for this. GuildController has been removed in 4.0 (over a year ago).

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the accepted answer x'] OP got a reply from the creator of JDA himself too